# How can i use .net Remoting over internet

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, nat, nat-traversal

I have two application on different computers than connect to each other by Remoting Channel.
I want to control server from client on different network (over Internet).

- How i can do that?
- Is it possible to configure Remoting to bypass/punch holes in NAT?

Comment: Did you do any research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I would recommend using [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) instead of Remoting, especially if you're going to try to work over the internet.

Neither technology will bypass your firewalls, though WCF does provide far more options for configuring the channel which is used for the communication.  This often makes it simpler to provide an endpoint that will work for internet connections and communication.